# ethernet cable run over 100meters (~450 feet) inconsistent bandwith – alternatives: POE extenders vs fiber

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, fiber

First yes I am aware the maximum recommended cat5 cable length is 100m. I am in a particular situation where I needed to run a bit farther than that and don't have power access for repeaters along the way. I had some of this cable and wanted to see the results.

Here's the ethernet cable "cat7" I'm using: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0BFFYJPMS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFFYJPMS) I shielded the connectors. The cable was tested to be working using one of those cable testers that came with the cable.

The main modem/router is connected to the ISP and then runs the 450ft ethernet cable to the WAN port of the 2nd router.

I ran this setup for about 2 months and had no connectivity issues whatsoever. I was getting almost the full 100mbps of my connection and detected no collisions in the router logs.

Fast forward to now, I can't go a day without the internet slowing down tremendously or dropping out completely. It is now winter and I am curious if the temperature could be affecting the effective transmission distance of the signal.

The whole time the 2nd router has recognized the signal from the primary router, and is getting an IP. It's just that the transmission speed will randomly drop tremendously.

On the primary router, the ports have been set to auto configuration for duplex. I tried manually setting them to full duplex 100mbps, and that didn't seem to change anything. When changing it to 1000mbps, my 2nd router completely lost the signal from main router (that was the only time that happened where there was no signal at all, no IP).

=================================================================================

tldr; I'm really curious to know why it was working so well for months and now not anymore – the only factor that really change I can think of is the temperature.

Is there anything in the logs I can do to find out why this might be happening, or is there no hope?

I should also mention the 2nd router I'm using is very old (Netgear wnr2000v5). I tried flashing it with openWRT and still am having the same connection speed issues. Maybe it is worth trying a newer router.

Aside from that, I've looked at alternatives using POE extenders, OR just running a new cable with fiber.  I'm looking for something quick and cheap for a temporary fix (maybe in the future I'll run fiber).

I looked at POE extenders, but even with that I'm under the impression I'd need to be buying a bit of equipment, including a POE switch, POE extenders.

Is it true that a POE extender alone will not help my situation going from one router to another router?

I'm also curious about the grounding consequences on my setup.  The two buildings are connected on the same ground

Comment: "*The cable was tested to be working using one of those cable testers*" - That's probably just a simple DC continuity tester. To see the effects of a long cable, you at least need to use a TDR meter. Time for oxidation, UV exposure, and moisture can contribute to changing/deteriorate the cable characteristics (e.g. L, C, & R, bandwidth, crosstalk). You neglect to mention if this cable was buried or suspended, or  within a conduit.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Actiontec-MoCA-Network-Adapter-Ethernet/dp/B088KV2YYL/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?crid=VG6RRRVK6HQ&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.VXlhFiLOyl6MX0x3ILyWWHlU657W7nN0ckTcp4nkSZWg7piTQQDC-Ntk-7VziX2olcwzAVCMhcJNSAIC-YAfCG8ISFTUULq1RIGCVOaeK87KgHJtqpSpizmt35XiOFeZ4B1cP_xR2vI3pXn9VSVx9QIVOW_dO-ECAOUIiwL5IXWLmUzXQA5Inn6IGtRw_7tvh3HG6IfdRG1KrCRjdROF2Q.GbyxoS3EucfwDeqtiYvANCYHOkNgCSIU62U_J_7jUfs&dib_tag=se&keywords=moca+adapter&qid=1705472628&sprefix=moca%2Caps%2C193&sr=8-3

Comment: thanks @sawdust it was never buried nor in conduit, just laying on the ground.  My goal was to bury it when the vegetation was lower and easier to do, but as of now it is not buried

Comment: "*Just laying on the ground*" means that the cable is completely unprotected, and adds the risk of physical damage, e.g. stepped on to cause sharp bends. Cable may look like rope, but needs to be handled more carefully. The damage may not be enough to cause a continuity failure, but could be sufficient to degrade Ethernet performance. Also check for rodent damage. Some cable sheathings have turned out to be unexpectedly delicious to some rodents.

Answer (score 1):

You state the cable is "just laying on the ground."

- As temperature changes, air in the cable expands and contracts.
- More air enters through the ends of the cable, and through any cuts or nicks.
- Air has water vapor (humidity).
- The water vapor condenses back to liquid inside that 450 foot run of cable, *vastly* changing the impedance by increasing the capacitance between conductors. This causes reflections inside the cable, and signal loss due to mismatch.
- Now, in winter, that water has frozen, further distorting the cable.

Also, you state you're using Cat 7 cable [which is *not* an approved standard](https://www.cablematters.com/Blog/Networking/what-is-cat7-and-why-you-don-t-need-it).

It might be better to install a low-voltage DC cable to power a WiFi link, such as [some of these.](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=outdoors%20wifi%20link) That cable should be in a protective cover, with lightning protection.

Comment: Thank you for the detail here.  Question – would these factors be the same for a direct buried cable vs "laying on the ground"?

Unless it's buried feet below the ground, I don't understand how any cable could avoid those factors from water in the soil.   Yet it is marketed as outdoor direct burial cable.

I did double check my cable with the cable tester, and the "G/ground" does not light up, meaning maybe I did not terminate the shields correctly.  Even so, as I understand this shielding would only help with EMF interference, not signal loss due to what you're describe, is that right?

Comment: As you state, buried below frost line, the ground has a fairly constant temperature. Sealing the cable inside conduit or tubing would help. Also, sealing the connectors at the end with rubber tape or silicone helps prevent moisture entering. The testers are DC, and only check that pins are connected, *not* loss. You'd need a costly TDR (Time Domain Reflectometer), as Sawdust states to know loss and mismatch. Finally, whatever you do, provide  lightning protection at each end!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give an update to the thread.

I ended up reflashing the 2nd router with OpenWRT.  The main router's LAN settings were kept at auto full duplex.

The cable remains unburied, laying above ground for now, and I have been getting close to 100mbps consistently for over a month now using it almost every day.

I was also using a VPN, and I think previously when I encountered slowness, it was not an issue of the cable but the perhaps the VPN.

Anyway, I know there are many factors here, but I can say at least for my situation, a 450 ft run using CAT7 cables (with the metal shielded connector plugs) has been working for me without issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).